# My local links for css and js assest are getting appended with localhost while redirecting to a page from a link

Tags: javascript, java, css, email, spring-mvc

My activation link that I send through email: http://localhost:8080/respondToInvitation/example@gmail.com/1

I use this link in my java controller to get an account with the respective email id to be activated and my code is this for activation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/respondToInvitation/{email}/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String respondToInvitationByEventCode(ModelMap modelMap,@PathVariable String id,@PathVariable String email){ 

    log.debug("Begin->respondToInvitationByEventCode::");

    User user = userDAO.getUserByEmail(email);

    if (user!= null && user.getId() != 0) {

        modelMap.put("status", "failure");
        modelMap.put("message", "The Email you entered is already registered!");

    } else {
        user = new User();
        user.setEmailId(email);
        user.setId(NumberUtils.toLong(id));
    }
    modelMap.put("user", user);
    return PageView.DEPENDANTSIGNUP;
  }
```

now when I click on above link from the mail i get 404 errors for css and js that I use in my jsp pages. Its showing this:
http://localhost:8080/respondToInvitation/pavankalyan.tolety12@gmail.com/css/bootstrap.min.css where localhost:8080/ must be followed by css and js scripts. Where is the mistake Im making here in java or mail link?

Comment: I don't do java but I'd imagine it is your HTTP Server doing the appending. Perhaps a ModRewrite Rule, of something within httpd.conf - just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ../../ to jump above slashes 2 times. ../ means one time jumping in url.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://localhost:8080/respondToInvitation/css/bootstrap.min.css " type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css " type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I've known this thing but I doubt if there is any case the above thing fails? i mean while hosted on a sever or difference in folder structure of where jsp and assets are located?

Comment: You can put relative path over there. `href=" http://localhost:8080/respondToInvitation/css/bootstrap.min.css "`

Comment: I use tiles in my java project where on I move all my assets to a single file and i append them in every file instead of writing them on every page. hope the work around suggested works. Thanks!